# Gradle error when trying to debug code in Intellij

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea

In one of my projects I get a gradle error message whenever I try to run code in debug mode (^D):

```
...
> Task :apps:travel-information-service:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :apps:travel-information-service:test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Initialization script '/private/var/folders/lx/lnqmbcy557ndwxld1hbsjlf00000gn/T/ijresolvers.gradle' line: 347
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':apps:travel-information-service:test'.
> System property 'idea.debugger.dispatch.port' is not set
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Searching for this issue did not give any results.

It does not matter which code I try to debug (Java applications, junit tests, etc all give the same error). Running the code normally (non-debug mode) works fine. My other projects are fine using the same version of Intellij. I have tried rebooting, invalidating the caches in Intellij, reimporting the gradle project, and even completely removing the .idea directory.

Any tips on how to investigate (or even fix ;-)) this issue are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bug should be fixed in 2020.2 version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245480